# How to filter data in GraphQL query in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am using GraphQL in Flutter. I do not have much experience of using GraphQL in Flutter. The code is given below:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final HttpLink link = HttpLink(
   uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
  );

 ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
  GraphQLClient(
  cache: InMemoryCache(),
  link: link,
 ),
);

runApp(MyApp(client: client));
}
```

I have to perform by calling the GraphQL query "launches" filtering by the “mission_name” field exposed by  this public backend: https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ . But I do not know how to do it. If anybody know how to do it then please help me. Thanks

Comment: API specific, search for `where` or `filter` (this case) - follow some tutorials

Comment: Have you reviewed this [tutorial](https://dev.to/joshuamdeguzman/integrating-graphql-in-flutter-using-graphqlflutter-5a61)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do filtering by using api specfic keyword for filtering. In case of https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ it is **find** keyword, for other api it might be **where** or **filter**  Below is example of the search done by calling the **GraphQL** query **"launches"** filtering by the **“mission_name”**. As a example i put **“mission_name” = "Thaicom 6"**, you can edit it according to your requirement.

```
query launchesDetails {
  launches(find: {
     mission_name: "Thaicom 6",
  })   {
     details
     id
     is_tentative
     launch_date_local
     launch_date_unix
     launch_date_utc
     launch_site {
         site_id
         site_name
     }
     launch_success
     launch_year
     mission_name
  }
}
```